# How to fix System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, listbox, unhandled-exception, sortedlist

I've got a booking system program, and one form lists the bookings already made depending on the date selected. All the times of the bookings made on the selected date were to be shown in the list box. The selected item in the list box would then populate the text boxes below with all the booking data.

However, I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

This is the bookingClass:

```
    public DateTime bookingDate
    {
        get
        {
            return myDate;
        }

        set
        {
            myDate = value;
        }
    }

    public string bookingTime
    {
        get
        {
            return myTime;
        }
        set
        {
            myTime = value;
        }
    }


    public int bookingID
    {
        get
        {
            return myID;
        }
        set
        {
            myID = value;
        }
    }


    public int customerID
    {
        get
        {
            return myCust;
        }
        set
        {
            myCust = value;
        }
    }


    public string bookingTicket
    {
        get
        {
            return myTicket;
        }
        set
        {
            myTicket = value;
        }
    }

    public int bookingQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            return myNum;
        }
        set
        {
            myNum = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal bookingTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return myTotal;
        }
        set
        {
            myTotal = value;
        }
    }


    //A SortedList of booking times is returned for a given Date
    public SortedList GetBookingsByDate(DateTime bookingDate)
    {
        newCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

        String firstConStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=";
        String pathToDB = "F:\\Level 5\\Object Oriented Programs\\Programs\\assignmentPractice\\assignmentPractice\\assignmentDB.mdf;";
        String lastConStr = "Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

        newCon.ConnectionString = firstConStr + pathToDB + lastConStr;

        newCon.Open();

        SqlCommand cmBookList = new SqlCommand();
        cmBookList.Connection = newCon;
        cmBookList.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmBookList.CommandText = "Select bookingID, bookingTime from Booking where bookingDate = '" + bookingDate.ToLongDateString() + "'";
        SqlDataReader drBookList = cmBookList.ExecuteReader();

        //This is a sorted list of key/value pairs
        SortedList BookList = new SortedList();

        //drBookList[0] is the key (Booking ID) and drBookList[1] is the value (Booking Time)
        while (drBookList.Read())
        {
            BookList.Add(drBookList[0], drBookList[1]);

        }
        drBookList.Close();
        newCon.Close();
        return BookList;
    }


}
```

This is the form:

```
    public bookingSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private SortedList BookList;
    private bookingClass objBooking;

    private void btnList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBook.Items.Clear();

        bookingClass objBooking = new bookingClass();

        BookList = objBooking.GetBookingsByDate(DateTime.Parse(dtpDate.Text));

        //Populate the ListBox with the Booking times
        if (BookList.Count == 0)
        {
            lstBook.Items.Add("No Records");
            return;
        }
        foreach (DictionaryEntry book in BookList)
        {
            lstBook.Items.Add(book.Value);
        }
        lstBook.SelectedIndex = 0;


    }

    private void lstBook_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BookList.Count > 0)     //Don't process if 'No Records'
        {
            //Get the Booking details for a particular selected time in the list
            //The SelectedIndex is used to read the Key value from the
            //SortedList which holds the bookingID
            objBooking.GetBookingsByDate((DateTime)BookList.GetKey(lstBook.SelectedIndex));

            txtID.Text = objBooking.bookingID.ToString();
            txtCust.Text = objBooking.customerID.ToString();
            txtTime.Text = objBooking.bookingTime;
            txtTicket.Text = objBooking.bookingTicket;
            txtNum.Text = objBooking.bookingQuantity.ToString();
            txtTotal.Text = objBooking.bookingTotal.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

It's highlighting this line when I get the error:

```
objBooking.GetBookingsByDate((DateTime)BookList.GetKey(lstBook.SelectedIndex))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the key is not a date of any sort. So `BookList.GetKey()` won't return anything that can be casted to a `DateTime`. Maybe you forgot one step actually getting the booking and extract the time from there?

Comment: Based on your sql, your key is the booking id and the value is the date. I think you want to use `GetByIndex()` instead of `GetKey()`.

Comment: The Key value is the booking ID, so it's an `int`. I was following a tutorial from my teacher on how to create it, but in her example it involves getting a category ID (`int`) to list a group of products, whereas mine uses a booking date (`DateTime`).

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a sorted list to then add items to a list box? Why don't you just bind a collection of books? You are relying on two disconnected collections to be in sync with the order of their id's, and I suppose they will be it but it seems awkward to me.

Comment: Just tried that, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Right... `GetKey` gets the **key**, which is an int. You want the **value**, which is a date, so use the method that gives you the value which is `GetByIndex`.

Comment: Split the line giving you the problem so you can debug it. What is the result of this: `var whatDoesThisGiveMe = BookList.GetByIndex(lstBook.SelectedIndex);` Maybe split that up even more to get the selected index separately and see if that is correct too.

Comment: Doing that sets the textboxes that are expecting `int` to 0. The list is populated with the times, so everything seems to be working with that.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to step through code in the debugger? I'm getting the impression you are just running the program and looking at what happens in the form.

Comment: I assumed you meant to just run it. I've not used the debugger before

Comment: Click on a line of code that you want to pause execution on then press F9. Now press F5 to execute your program with the debugger. When your program stops on the breakpoint you can inspect in-scope variables by hovering you mouse over them or several other means like the locals window as one example.

Comment: The `whatDoesThisGiveMe` is `null`, the BookList count is 3 and the selected index is 0.

Comment: It's hard to say at this point now that your code is different than your original question. Narrow down where the problem is by doing a test with a known good value and see what you get: `objBooking.GetBookingsByDate(*...a known good DateTime here...*);`

Comment: tried `objBooking.GetBookingsByDate(dtpDate.Value).GetByIndex(lstBook.SelectedIndex);`. This gave me the right list of times, but when each one was selected, the textboxes still displayed either zeroes or were blank.